# How to use WSO2 ESB to set message format to MQSTR

Tags: jms, wso2, esb, mq

I am using WSO2 ESB 4.9 to connect to a WebSphere MQ queue via a .bindings file. By default, WSO2 ESB sends the MQ messages via JMS with the format MQHRF2. How can I configure WSO2 ESB so that it would send the MQ messages in the MQSTR format instead, similar to the following Java coding:

`Queue myQueue = session.createQueue("queue:///myQueue?targetClient=1");`

or

```
((MQQueue) queue).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Here is part of my proxy as configured on WSO2 ESB per suggestion as below:

```
     <outSequence>
     <property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
     <property name="JMS_IBM_Format"
               value="MQSTR"
               scope="transport"
               type="STRING"/>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <endpoint>
     <address uri="jms:/xxxx?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=..."
              format="soap11"/>
  </endpoint>
```

The following property setting is used to remove the unwanted HTTP header info from the upstream (JSON/HTTP) by not sending it to the downstream (XML/JMS):

```
<property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following property before sending it to the MQ.

```
 <property name="JMS_IBM_Format"
               value="MQSTR"
               scope="transport"
               type="STRING"/>
<send>
    <!-- your MQ endpoint here -->
</send>
```

Comment: Hello .... Thanks for having posted your suggestion so quickly. I have tested your solution but it did not work though, i.e. the MQ header format remains unchanged with MQHRF2.

Comment: when we add that property, it gets passed as a header with the message to MQ (there's no special processing done in addition to that). In your case, does the header value received at MQ remain as 'MQHRF2'?  or else are you referring to the header of a message received at esb from MQ? also what's the MQ version/environment?

Comment: Hello ... It seems that WSO2 ESB ignores the above property setting without throwing any error so the header value received on MQ server remains as MQHRF2. If I use Java JMS code to send an MQ message by setting the MQ header format to MQSTR, my MQ server has no issue to receive the proper MQ message header as expected. So I doubt the underlying issue is related to my MQ environment (receiver).

Comment: that's quite weird since we've been able to send messages in MQSTR format in the recent past with ESB 4.9.0 (to MQ 7.1). You can try adding an 'action' parameter in the property configuration. i.e.  action="set"  to explicitly set the property

Comment: <property name="JMS_IBM_Format"
               value="MQSTR"
               scope="transport"
               type="STRING" action="set"/>

Comment: in addition if it doesn't work, try using 'header' mediator instead of property mediator as:  <header name=".... (similar to pervious property declaration)

Comment: Hello ... Many thanks for your quick comment. I updated my post with part of my proxy configuration. Not sure if I did anything wrong there.

Comment: in your jms endpoint i see format="soap11", which may be overriding the jms headers. try removing that and see. also try the above suggestions.

Comment: Hello ... I would need to keep the attribute of format="soap11" so that the WSO2 ESB output to MQ is sent/received in XML.

Comment: having messageType as application/xml should be enough for that.

Comment: Hi John, did you ever resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem using v 6.4.0 of the ESB (integrator)